# Select2, a jQuery dependent plugin does not need to be shimmed in RequireJS. Is this correct behavior?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Select2 (v3.4.5) is a jQuery plugin, so RequireJS' documentation leads me to believe that I have to `shim` Select2 and declare jQuery as a dependency if I want to use it in conjunction with RequireJS. But in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2vvq8d8/) I can use Select2 without having to `shim` it.

Can anyone say why?

Comment: Probably just luck that Cloudflare's servers are loading slower for you than Google's servers. I tried using a slower server to load jQuery (unminified) and it threw an error (as expected).

Comment: you must have to shim select2 v 3.4.5 because this lib version not support modular , and your fiddle its working because jquery is loading faster than select2